# How to copy or select current string in terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I want to copy current string (or select and then copy with help ctrl+shift+c) to clipboard. How do I make this?

Comment: does it is not work?

Comment: @KasiyA, what do you mean, saying "it"?

Comment: @hbdgaf, I want to copy a command string, not result.

Comment: First select string by mouse and then copy(Ctlr+Shift+C) and paste the copied string by Ctrl+Shift+V. did you see any changes?

Comment: @KasiyA, yep, It does work. But, I have to use a mouse. I with to use only shortcuts.

Comment: Without selecting string how do you want to copy them?? And one more question. What did you mean about "current string"???

Comment: @KasiyA, there is ctrl+a shortcut for selecting in Windows. I want something like that in Ubuntu.

Comment: @KasiyA, current string is something like that: ">cat file.txt | grep "a" | wc -1".

Comment: then I can duplicate your question...